# Complex HTML/CSS Layout Positioning

Tags: html, css

I have this complex HTML Layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/5RgjL/2/

As you can see, messages are anchored at the top of the `#messages` container.

I want it so they are anchored at bottom, so the first message displayed will be at bottom, and not at the top.

Also when resizing the page the view inside the scrolling box must slide up from bottom.
It is hard to explain, i will make you understand with an example:

Populate messages inside the box, till is full and there is the scroll bar.
Try to resize the entire window from bottom, you can see that the message on bottom will be covered. i do not want this, but instead, slide up from bottom.

I tried many things, like to absolute positioning the `#message` container, but i run into other problems and i cannot get it to work like i want.

I need some help from someone really experienced in HTML/CSS.

If you are familiar with the Facebook messages page, you will understand what i'm trying to do.

PS: Some CSS styles are applied with javascript, because i generate page content dinamically, and only in this page i need those styles.

Comment: woudnt it be better to have your messages at the top rather than the bottom. and put your new one above the old once. I think this is something that you would need to add into your jquery

Comment: No, i don't like that, because in the container at the bottom of the messages there is a form box, so new messages must be at bottom, like facebook does.

Comment: what about position:fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then setting an absolute bottom position for the messages *until* there are more messages than vertical space will solve the first requirement of new messages appearing at the bottom.

This requires a CSS and JavaScript change:

**CSS**

```
#messagesWrapper {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $messages = $('#messages');
var $messagesWrapper = $('#messagesWrapper');
var $messagePageContent = $('#messagePageContent');  

function populateMessages(){
    var newMessage = $('<div id="msg-'+i+'" class="aMessage">Another Message<br>Message ID: '+i+'</div>');
    i++;
    newMessage.hide().appendTo('#messages').stop().fadeIn(400);

    if ($messages.height() >= $messagePageContent.height()){
        messagesWrapper .css({position:'static'});
        $messagePageContent.stop().animate({ scrollTop: $messages.outerHeight() }, 700);
    }    
}
```

The scrolling also needs to occur if then window is resized, so attaching a handle to the resize event is also required.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $messagePageContent.stop().animate({ scrollTop: $messages.outerHeight() }, 700);
});
```

However, this is not good enough because the *height calculation* is missing which resets the CSS `position` to its default value. This is required for the [`enscroll`](http://enscrollplugin.com/) jQuery plugin (and I suspect any sort of scrolling) to work.

But we can simply refactor and move all of the code into a common function, for example:

```
var $messages = $('#messages');
var $messagesWrapper = $('#messagesWrapper');
var $messagePageContent = $('#messagePageContent');  

function populateMessages(){
    var newMessage = $('<div id="msg-'+i+'" class="aMessage">Another Message<br>Message ID: '+i+'</div>');
    i++;

    newMessage.hide().appendTo('#messages').stop().fadeIn(400);
    scrollMessages();
}

function scrollMessages() {
    if ($messages.height() >= $messagePageContent.height()){
        $messagesWrapper.css({position:'static'});
        $messagePageContent.stop().animate({ scrollTop: $messages.outerHeight() }, 700);
    }
}

$(window).resize(scrollMessages);
```

This is the code I used in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uSmHC/). It's probably not the best solution, I was looking at using `-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1)` to flip the container and then flip the messages back but it messed up the scrolling (i.e. it was backwards!). There might be a better solution using CSS transforms out there.

Comment: Thank you! That's solve one problem, but creates another. If the scrollBar is not at the end, it does not need to be scrolled down when resizing. But i think i can workaround this by checking if the scrollbar is at bottom or not.If it is, scroll down, else not. I will test it and try to fix this, by now thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was just my misunderstanding of your requirements. I was not sure what sort of automatic scrolling you wanted. You should be able to just remove the `scrollTop` animation or like you said, put a condition around it.

Comment: Ok i have fixed it http://jsfiddle.net/d2vtW/1/ but there is only one small problem, but with the current layout i think is not possible to fix: When the scroll bar is not at bottom, and resizing the window, the messages do not slide up, they stay in fixed position, always anchored at top, so resizing the window cause the last message to be covered.

Comment: On my fiddle, with lots of messages and a scroll position not at the bottom, when resizing the window the messages are scrolled to the bottom again. Is this what you want? If so I think it might just be a case of removing the `if checkScrollBottom()` check in the `.resize()`.

Comment: I tried with 250 messages, and they do not scroll at bottom, there is only a 30px of flexibility. if the scrollbar is 30px from bottom it does scroll otherwise not. But if i remove the check on .resize() even if the scrollbar is at the top, they scroll, and is not what i want, but some sort of scrolling to mantain the messages in positio, so the first message on top will be hidden, not the last one.

Comment: I guess I am not really understanding the requirement then. Here's what I did with my fiddle: add 30 messages, scroll up about half way so messages 11-16 are visible, then I resize the browser window, either by grabbing the jsFiddle result pane and making it taller. The resize scrolls the messages back down to the bottom. So if there are 30 messages and 11-16 are in view and you resize the height of the window, which messages should be in view after the resize event?

Comment: On my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d2vtW/1  if the scrollbar is not at the bottom, resizing the window will not cause the messages to scroll down. I dunno. Anyway, if messages 11-16 are in view, so the n°16 is the last, after the resize event to make the window SMALLER, the last message on bottom must be n° 16 and the first one, 12,13 depending on how much resize.

Answer (score 0):

You can have them added to the bottom by applying this style to your messages id:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Also, if you want the images to add to the top of the list instead of to the bottom you can use prependTo() instead of appendTo().

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking for on the scrolling, so if you could give a bit more info I will update my answer.

Comment: it doesn't. You killed the scrolling part :P

Comment: Ahhh, I see what your saying. I will revise my answer

Comment: But, the messages positioning like your example is perfect, and solve also the "scrolling" problem that you didn't understand. It is all related to the anchoring of the messages.